# NetSuite integration testing

Tags: postman, integration, netsuite, boomi, netsuite-rest-api

I haven't used Postman in about 3 years and when I did use it I was a novice.  What I'm trying to do is get all the fields that a table has available in order to create the profile I want in another platform (Dell Boomi).

I'm pulling `services/rest/record/v1/CUSTOMER` but that is only giving me the internal IDs.
I'm trying to do the SQL equivalent of:

`SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER`

and/or

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tableName'`

Comment: I have tried 'record/v1/customer?bodyFields=internalId,entityId,companyName,email'.  Looking for the API equivalent to 'app.netsuite.com/app/recordscatalog/rcbrowser.nl?whence=#/record_ss/Customer'